# mysql union optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, union

**QUERY 1**

```
(
SELECT 
    a.image_name, a.member_id, b.username, c.image_alt , c.img_id, 
a.total_views, c.island_id, c.personal, c.date_upload, COUNT(d.img_id) AS numComm  
FROM 
    members_stats_images a, members b, members_images c, members_images_comments d  
WHERE 
    c.island_id='$island_id'  AND 
    c.personal='N' AND 
    c.approved='Y' AND
    c.is_other<>'Y' AND   
    c.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.image_name=c.image_name AND 
    d.img_id=c.img_id 
GROUP BY 
    d.img_id 
)
UNION 
(
SELECT 
    a.image_name, a.member_id, b.username, c.image_alt , c.img_id, 
a.total_views, c.island_id, c.personal, c.date_upload, 0 AS numComm  
FROM 
    members_stats_images a, members b, members_images c 
WHERE 
    c.island_id='$island_id' AND 
    c.personal='N' AND 
    c.approved='Y' AND 
    c.is_other<>'Y' AND 
    c.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.image_name=c.image_name AND 
    c.img_id NOT IN (SELECT img_id FROM members_images_comments GROUP BY img_id) 
)           

ORDER BY 
    numComm DESC, date_upload DESC 
LIMIT 
    $set_limit, $li
```

**QUERY 2**

```
(
SELECT 
    a.image_name, a.member_id, b.username, c.image_alt , c.img_id, 
a.total_views, c.island_id, c.personal, c.date_upload, COUNT(e.img_id) AS numComm  
FROM 
    members_stats_images a, members b, members_images c, members_photo_see_do d,
 members_images_comments e  
WHERE 
    c.island_id='$island_id' AND 
    c.personal='N' AND 
    c.approved='Y' AND 
    c.is_other<>'Y' AND 
    c.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.image_name=c.image_name AND 
    c.img_id=d.img_id AND 
    d.village_id='$village_id' AND 
    e.img_id=c.img_id 
GROUP BY 
    e.img_id 
)
UNION 
(
SELECT 
    a.image_name, a.member_id, b.username, c.image_alt , c.img_id, 
a.total_views, c.island_id, c.personal, c.date_upload, 0 AS numComm  
FROM 
    members_stats_images a, members b, members_images c, members_photo_see_do d 
WHERE 
    c.island_id='$island_id' AND 
    c.personal='N' AND 
    c.approved='Y' AND 
    c.is_other<>'Y' AND 
    c.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.member_id=b.member_id AND 
    a.image_name=c.image_name AND 
    c.img_id=d.img_id AND 
    d.village_id='$village_id' AND 
    c.img_id NOT IN (SELECT img_id FROM members_images_comments GROUP BY img_id)
)           

ORDER BY 
    numComm DESC, date_upload DESC 
LIMIT 
    $set_limit, $limit
```

As you can see, the two queries are very similar.

The second query is executed in a couple of seconds, while the first query is executed in more than 2 minutes.

Can any one suggest anything to improve the first query?

**NOTE:** all tables involved have indexes in all id fields.

**EDIT**
Following advice from @G-Nugget, i wrote the above queries with JOINs, something like:

```
    SELECT  
        c.img_id, c.image_name, c.member_id, c.image_alt, c.island_id, c.personal, c.date_upload, b.username,  c.island_id, c.personal, c.date_upload, 
        a.total_views,  
        COUNT(e.img_id) AS numComm 
    FROM members_images AS c 
    LEFT JOIN members_stats_images AS a ON c.image_name=a.image_name AND c.member_id=a.member_id
    LEFT JOIN members AS b ON c.member_id=b.member_id 
    LEFT JOIN members_photo_see_do AS d ON c.img_id=d.img_id 
    LEFT JOIN members_images_comments AS e ON c.img_id=e.img_id 
    WHERE 
    c.island_id='$island_id' AND 
    c.personal='N' AND 
    c.approved='Y' AND 
    c.is_other<>'Y' AND 
    d.see_id='$see_id' 
    GROUP BY c.img_id
```

It is now executed perfectly without delays.

Comment: How about you post the `EXPLAIN` of both statements and their indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only difference between the two queries is the addition of the `members_photo_see_do` table, clearly there IS an index missing to support the join from it to `members_images`.

It is impossible to say more than that without much more information about the queries and the table definitions.

Also, you will find that both reading and thinking about the queries is eased considerably by using the modern JOIN syntax. You will also find members here more receptive to helping you if you adopt it. Please write your queries using it when you call back.

Comment: @G_Nugget yes, JOINs did the work. it is now working perfectly. Thanks.